# How to re-use the useEffect hook properly

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm now switching from a class based component to a function with hooks, and I need some time getting used to it.

I want the user to be able to upload a main profile picture and 6 secondary images, the images will be uploaded to a server. I have created the logic that handles the main profile picture upload, but now I want to re-use that logic to also upload the other pictures to the server with the same piece of code.

My logic now is:

1. Get userData and main profile image from server.
2. When clicked on the edit button it will open a image picker.
3. When the picture has been chosen it changes the state called imageChanged to true and then the useEffect activates and executes the function called _uploadImage(); Then is check if the image has been set or if its just a false flag.
4. The image will be uploaded to the server by using PHP.

Here is my profile screen:

[image]

```js
const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);
const [imageChanged, setimageChanged] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
        function _uploadImage() {
            if (imageChanged !== null) {
                var data = new FormData();
                data.append('action', 'uploadProfileImage');
                data.append('profileID', userInfo.ProfileId);
                data.append('file', {
                    uri: selectedImage.uri,
                    type: 'image/jpg',
                    name: 'tempimage.jpg'
                });
                fetch('', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: data,
                    headers: {
                        Accept: 'application/json'
                    }
                })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(responseJson => {
                        if (responseJson[0].Result == 1) {
                            console.log(responseJson)
                        } else {
                            //alert('Niet gelukt, probeer het later opnieuw')
                        }
                        setimageChanged(false);
                    });
            }
        };

        _uploadImage();
    }, [selectedImage])

async function _pickImage() {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            mediaTypes: 'Images',
            quality: 0.7
        });
        if (!result.cancelled) {
            if (result.type === 'image') {
                setSelectedImage(result);
                setimageChanged(true);
            } else {
                alert('Upload een geldige image');
                console.log('No image found');
            }
        }
    };
```

And here is the render:

```js
<Card
    containerStyle={{
        padding: 0,
        marginTop: 30,
        marginRight: 0,
        marginLeft: 0,
        alignItems: 'center'
    }}
>
    <Avatar
        source={{ uri: '?time=' + Date.now() }}
        size="xlarge"
        rounded
        showEditButton={true}
        editButton={{ size: 30 }}
        onEditPress={() => {
            _pickImage();
        }}
        title={'n'}
    />
    <Text>
        {userInfo.FirstName + ' ' + userInfo.LastName}
    </Text>
    <Text>
        {userInfo.BirthDate + ' Jaar, ' + userInfo.City}
    </Text>
</Card>
<Card
    containerStyle={{
        padding: 0,
        marginTop: 30,
        marginRight: 0,
        marginLeft: 0,
        alignItems: 'center'
    }}
>
    <FlatList style={{ margin: 5 }}
        data={[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
        numColumns={3}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
        renderItem={(item) => <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { _pickImage() }}><View key={item.id} style={{ width: 100, margin: 3.5, borderRadius: 10, justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: '#ddd', height: 100 }}><Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 20 }}>+</Text></View></TouchableOpacity>}
    />
</Card>
```

So to summarize I want to be able to re-use the pickimage and upload image code to upload the other photos, but I want to avoid declaring 6 states at the top and constantly checking if one of those change, and the problem then is that i don't know the index of the picked image.